# Oracle Apex - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex-5

I'm getting the ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER error while trying to query the following:

```
case
    when PRODUCT_NAME = 'Something' and PRICE is not null 
    and QUANTITY > 0 
    then :P4_MY_NUMERIC_ITEM
    else 1
end MY_COLUMN
```

(item :p4 is a pre-filled (via computation) item. Value = 1 )
Funny (weird) thing is that it works when I actually select a number it works (but it's not what I need since the Item should be editable by the user):

```
case
    when PRODUCT_NAME = 'Something' and PRICE is not null 
    and QUANTITY > 0 
    then 2
    else 1
end MY_COLUMN
```

Does anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it keeping my item in the query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this do?

```
else '1'
```

Because, Apex items are *strings* so `:P4_MY_NUMERIC_ITEM` (although containing numbers) is a string. `CASE` expects the same datatype, i.e.

```
case when ... then <string>
              else <expects a string as well, hence '1' and not just 1>
end
```

---

Alternatively, *convert* the `:P4` item to a *number*:

```
case when ... then to_number(:P4_MY_NUMERIC_ITEM)
              else 1
end
```

Answer (score 2):

A `case` expression returns a single value, which is of a single type.  All the branches should have the same type.

Despite its name `:P4_MY_NUMERIC_ITEM` appears to be a string.  You have two choices:

1. Use the appropriate type of `:P4_MY_NUMERIC_ITEM`.
2. Or, change the `else` to return a string: `else '1'`.